# Can I use Google turn server in my own app?

Tags: webrtc

I have a webrtc application and I am using Google TURN servers used by appr.tc in my own app and it's working fine.

Any idea what are the limitations and implications of using Google TURN server in my own app?

Comment: Are you using google turn servers directly or by fetching list of turn servers from appr.tc?

Comment: fetching from appr.tc. Essentially using entire code of android sample app in my own app

Comment: by fetching turn servers from appr.tc you get new username and password of turn servers and so there will be no problem. username and passwords of google turn servers have expire date.

Comment: I know that but what are the limitation? since it's for demo purpose, I am sure there are limitations.